# React - syntax - how to write in ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to follow along with this tutorial: https://www.viget.com/articles/building-a-multi-step-registration-form-with-react

I am getting stuck because this tutorial does not use ES6, so I'm trying to learn the differences at the same time as figure out if there are any issues in the tutorial documents.

I am getting a syntax error in this block of code. It says I've used a ',' where I should have a ';'. I don't know if that is related to ES6 or not. I tried replacing the comma, but I get the same error.

```
saveValues: function(field_value) {
    return function() {
      fieldValues = assign({}, fieldValues, field_value)
    }.bind(this)()
  },
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this?

The full page is currently set up as:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

var AccountFields   = require('./AccountFields');
var Confirmation    = require('./Confirmation');
var Success         = require('./Success');
var SurveyFields    = require('./SurveyFields');
var assign          = require('object-assign');


var fieldValues = {
  name  :null,
  email :null,
  password :null,
  organisation :null,
  interest  :[]
}



// import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
// import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap'

class Registration extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = function() {
    return {
      step: 1
    }
  },

  saveValues: function(field_value) {
    return function() {
      fieldValues = assign({}, fieldValues, field_value)
    }.bind(this)()
  },

  nextStep: function() {
    this.setState({
        step : this.state.step + 1
    })
  },

  previousStep: function() {
    this.setState({
      step : this.state.step - 1
    })
  },

  submitRegistration: function() {
    switch (this.state.step) {
      case 1:
        return <AccountFields fieldValues={fieldValues}
                              nextStep={this.nextStep}
                              previousStep={this.previousStep}
                              saveValues={this.saveValues}
                />

        case 2:
          return <SurveyFields  fieldValues={fieldValues}
                                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                                previousStep={this.previousStep}
                                saveValues={this.saveValues}
                  />

        case 3:
          return <Confirmation  fieldValues={fieldValues}
                                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                                submitRegistration={this.submitRegistration}
                 />

        case 4:
          return <Success fieldValues={fieldValues} />
    }
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <span className="progress-step"> Step {this.state.step}</span>
        <progress className="progress"></progress>
        {this.showStep()}
      </main>

    )
  }

export.default = Registration;
```

UPDATED ATTEMPT

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

var AccountFields   = require('./AccountFields');
var Confirmation    = require('./Confirmation');
var Success         = require('./Success');
var SurveyFields    = require('./SurveyFields');
var assign          = require('object-assign');


var fieldValues = {
  name  :null,
  email :null,
  password :null,
  organisation :null,
  interest  :[]
}



// import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
// import * as ReactBootstrap from 'react-bootstrap'

class Registration extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = function() {
    return {
      step: 1
    }
  }

  saveValues(field_value) {
    return function() {
      fieldValues = assign({}, fieldValues, field_value)
    }.bind(this)()
  }

  nextStep() {
    this.setState({
        step : this.state.step + 1
    })
  }

  previousStep() {
    this.setState({
      step : this.state.step - 1
    })
  }

  submitRegistration() {
    switch (this.state.step) {
      case 1:
        return <AccountFields fieldValues={fieldValues}
                              nextStep={this.nextStep}
                              previousStep={this.previousStep}
                              saveValues={this.saveValues}
                />

        case 2:
          return <SurveyFields  fieldValues={fieldValues}
                                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                                previousStep={this.previousStep}
                                saveValues={this.saveValues}
                  />

        case 3:
          return <Confirmation  fieldValues={fieldValues}
                                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                                submitRegistration={this.submitRegistration}
                 />

        case 4:
          return <Success fieldValues={fieldValues} />
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <span className="progress-step"> Step {this.state.step}</span>
        <progress className="progress"></progress>
        {this.showStep()}
      </main>

    )
  }


  }
}

export.default = Registration;
```

Comment: Here's the syntax for [defining a method in a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods). It doesn't involve a `:`. Also, it appears that you're missing a closing `}` for the class definition.

Comment: Thanks @4castle - the : comes from the tutorial - do you think that's wrong.  Do you mean that there is a missing } in the saveValues class? There are an equal number of opening and closing {} in that block. Sorry, obviously, I'm slow to learn but not sure where to find the starting point.

Comment: I took your updated code a pasted in Webstorm.  Your missing a "}" at the end of the constructor() { ...

Answer (score 1):

A couple things - you are defining functions and static variables within a Class, not building out an Object like you are used to.

Look into Javascript Classes, and you'll learn more about the `constructor()` function.  No comma is needed at the end.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = function() {
    return {
      step: 1
    }
  },    // <-----------
```

And, you won't identify name/value pairs for functions like this

```
saveValues: function
```

Instead, to define a function for the class it would be like

```
saveValues() {
   ...
}
```

Or

```
saveValues = () => {
  ...
}
```

Which will also bind `this`

I recommend a good IDE for helping you find simple syntax issues quickly.  WebStorm saves hours of time, many issues can be found by the linter and are exposed quickly.

Comment: Thanks @Swards. I couldnt understand the JetBrains ruby IDE when I was trying to learn it. I use atom now, but will give JB another try with JS. I actually can't make sense of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods. I've updated my attempt but it still gives the same error. Feeling really stupid, but is there a for dummies guide to this reference material?

Comment: Stick with it, it's easier than you think.  This book by https://stackoverflow.com/users/717950/axel-rauschmayer is great for explaining http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_core-features.html

Comment: I've been trying to learn for 5 years and 1 month. 4 hours every day. I could have gone back to uni and learned the full CS program in less time. I'm really still stuck for how to start. Clearly not taking to learning this smoothly. Thanks for the reference material. I'm working through it this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there's a few things I've noticed here. First, your `state`, is defined as a function and is returning an object. Why not just define it as an object to begin with? See here for documentation on how state is normally defined: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Also, you're binding your functions to `this` **inline**. Not necessarily anti-pattern, but it adds a lot of clutter when reading the code. You may want to consider binding those functions in the constructor. You also defined a `const` object that can easily be defined as part of the state itself. Not to mention, there's a lot of missing semi-colons and other syntax-related issues I've noticed.

Here's how I would refactor this (ES6):

```
import React from 'react';
import AccountFields from "./AccountFields";
import Confirmation from "./Confirmation";
import Success from "./Success";
import SurveyFields from "./SurveyFields";

export default class Registration extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      step: 1,
      fieldValues: {
        name: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
        organisation: null,
        interest: []
      }
    };

    this.saveValues = this.saveValues.bind(this);
    this.nextStep = this.nextStep.bind(this);
    this.previousStep = this.previousStep.bind(this);
  }

  saveValues(newFieldValue) {
    this.setState({
      fieldValues: newFieldValue,
    });
  }

  nextStep() {
    this.setState({
      step: this.state.step++
    });
  }

  previousStep() {
    this.setState({
      step: this.state.step --
    });
  }

  submitRegistration() {
    switch (this.state.step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <AccountFields
            fieldValues={this.state.fieldValues}
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            previousStep={this.previousStep}
            saveValues={this.saveValues}
          />);

      case 2:
        return (
          <SurveyFields
            fieldValues={this.state.fieldValues}
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            previousStep={this.previousStep}
            saveValues={this.saveValues}
          />);

      case 3:
        return (
          <Confirmation
            fieldValues={this.state.fieldValues}
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            submitRegistration={this.submitRegistration}
          />);

      case 4:
        return <Success fieldValues={this.state.fieldValues} />;

      // You should probably add a default case here.
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <span className="progress-step"> Step {this.state.step}</span>
        <progress className="progress"/>
        {/* Use the state, and not a non-existent function */}
        `{this.state.step}/4`
      </main>

    );
  }
}
```

I highly recommend you read through the React tutorials before trying to delve into too much ES5 -> ES6 parsing (even if it looks like a semi-decent tutorial). There's some big differences, but it looks like the underlying logic to this tutorial is somewhat lacking.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I tried to use your example, and after reviewing the react materials again, I'm still unclear about how to use it. The error messages after trying your approach introduce this: ERROR in ./~/react-dom/lib/traverseAllChildren.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner' in '/Users. I'll try leaving it for a couple of days and coming back with hopefully fresher eyes. Thank you anyway.